# Execute Shell command over MySql on remote host

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to login into a remote mysql machine and execute commands using 'system' on the remote machine.
I can log into the remote machine, but commands using: 'system' are executed at my local machine.
Thanks indeed!

I using mysql to connect from 'Host1' to 'Host2' using the command

```
mysql -uUsername -p data_base_name -h Host2
```

When I execute

```
'system hostname'
```

after I'm connected i get.

```
'Host1'
```

Comment: y not using mysql -u user -pPassword -h localhost? please explain

Comment: I'm connecting to the machine using
mysql -uuser -p database_name -h remote_hostname.

Comment: If I then call 'system hostname' I see that this command is executed on the machine I connect from.

Comment: Are you using SSH? What technologies are u using? what languages? please provide more details with scripts

Comment: I cannot log into my remote host using ssh. I don't know why.
I need to do some log analysis and the only option I have is to connect to that machine using mysql. I can connect to that machine!

Comment: Luckily (not for you) MySQL can not execute shell commands. I say luckily, because I can just imagine a whole new world of SQL injections if it did.

Comment: Is your user has the FILE permission, you can try `SELECT LOAD_FILE('/var/log/logfile')` to get to some of the log files, if they happen to be world-readable...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I cannot log into my remote host using ssh. I don't know why. I need to do some log analysis and the only option I have is to connect to that machine using mysql. I can connect to that machine! –

As far as I know, this is definitely not possible. It's far beyond the scope of mySQL, and there would be immense security implications if it were.

I don't think there is an alternative to getting SSH (or some other service that might help) running again.

Comment: Thanks, I need to search another method to connect to the server.

Answer (score 3):

Consider doing a select into outfile and writing script code into a place that will be executed on the server. For example, if mysql is running as root on the server, you be able to add something to the /etc/rc2.d which will get executed on the server during boot time.

Alternatively, if there is a file which is used as a source for scheduling tasks you may be able to overwrite that again using "select into outfile."

Comment: Clever! Using inotify or any similar filesystem event tool in a small daemon one could provide a `system` procedure with the expected functionality

Answer (score 0):

system runs local commands on your box. If you need to do anything with logs, either contact your hoster, to provide a way to download them or access them.